# Java syntax: NonWildcardTypeArguments

Tags: java, syntax, jls

The following is defined in chapter 18 of jls https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-18.html

```
NonWildcardTypeArguments:
    < TypeList >

TypeList:  
    ReferenceType { , ReferenceType }

ReferenceType:
    Identifier [TypeArguments] { . Identifier [TypeArguments] }

TypeArguments: 
    < TypeArgument { , TypeArgument } >

TypeArgument:  
    ReferenceType
    ? [ (extends | super) ReferenceType ]
```

According to the name of NonWildcardTypeArguments, it should not allow wild card. But the following code compiles

```
public class NonWildcardTypeArgumentsTest {
    public void test(Test<java.util.Set<? extends Object>> args) {

    }
}

class Test<T> {}
```

The type arguments in this example satisfies the definition of NonWildcardTypeArguments and it contains wild card:

```
<java.util.Set<? extends Object>>
```

I am confused by this. Why is it valid? Thanks

Comment: As a side note, this is not in JLS8

Comment: This is from chapter 18 of jls7.

Comment: Yes I just mentioned that it has been removed in JLS 8.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reminding! I just opened the jls8 version and I have to start from the scratch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wildcard is a type argument to `Set`, not `Test`. The grammar here is a tree-like structure, where each type argument applies to the type outside of it.

```
Test<T>
     ↓
    Set<E>
        ↓
    ? extends Object
```

`NonWildcardTypeArguments` only requires that each type argument is a `ReferenceType`, which `Set<? extends Object>` satisfies, since it's of the form `Identifier<TypeArgument>`. (`? extends Object` is a `TypeArgument`, but not a `ReferenceType`.)

For example, `<Set<? extends Object>>` is a `NonWildcardTypeArguments` but `<? extends Set<Object>>` is not.

So yes, there is a wildcard "in" the type arguments, but it's nested down a level in the tree. The `NonWildcardTypeArguments` construct only cares about the arguments directly inside of it.

Anyway, as assylias pointed out, this grammatical construct does not seem to exist anymore but I suppose the explanation is still interesting. (I tried searching the JLS 8 PDF for 'NonWildcardTypeArguments' and didn't come up with anything.)

Comment: I have read chapter 19 (Syntax) of JLS8 a little bit. It even looks more confusing to me. For example,  the six name constructs defined here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5 seem to be the same thing to me. After all, what I need is to understand java syntax from a parser's perspective. So it does not really matter how they name the constructs. Thanks for putting the post back. And thanks for the nice explanation.

Comment: All of the grammatical constructs are used contextually. If you're trying to learn about them, you might be looking at them from the wrong direction by looking at definitions. You have to understand how they're used to understand why they exist the way they do. 6.5.1 e.g. describes the process where names are interpeted. Also, same as with the type arguments, notice that the name constructs are tree structures. (Javac represents the trees very literally as a data structure.)